# Custom broadcast receiver block notification to display on Android - IBM mobilefirst

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, ibm-mobilefirst

I wanted to detect when notification  arrived in the application. From the documentation, we can't use native android API for notification on Hyrbide application. 
I followed this guide 
 to detect when notification arrived then send data to javascript part : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_push_notifications_hybrid.html

The problem is the notification is well received by the broadcast receiver but it is not displayed. Here is the code of the broadcastreceiver :

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();       
    String action = getPackageName() + "." + getString(R.string.app_name) + ".C2DM_MESSAGE";
    //Register Custom Push Broadcast Receiver
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {               
                Log.d("test", "action :" + intent.getAction());
                Log.d("test", "notification received)
                abortBroadcast();       
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(action));
}
```

Comment: What is purpose of overriding and using your own BroadcastReceiver? This is not a supported configuration

Comment: The purpose was to send event to the javascript part once a notification was received. Actually the first goal was to detect that the notification was click but i didn't find anything about it ...

Comment: Actually I solved the issue by creating a class that extend BroadcastReceiver instead of using registerReceiver method.
But if you have any info about detecting user click on notification I am taking ! thx ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by not using registerReceiver but using a custom class :

```
public class MyNotificationReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")){
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("notifReceived",  true);
            Log.d("test", "is the notif background ? ");
            WL.getInstance().sendActionToJS("androidNotif", data);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And in your manifest add :

```
<receiver android:name=".MyNotificationReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.your.appname"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```